# Singleton bound

Tags: coding-theory

I am looking at the proof of the singleton bound and I don't understand the first step.
I want to show that $A_q(n,d)\leq q^{n-d+1}$ where $A_q(n,d)$ is the code of maximal size given these parameters, d is the distance of the code, n the length, q the size of the alphabet.

The first step consist in the erasing of the first $d-1$ coordinates of an arbitrary code of distance $d$. After that the claim is that the resulting code has the same size of the original one since the distance is d. But take for instance the following binary code

$(110),(101),(011),(111)$

Then the code has distance 2 and erasing the first coordinate I get

$(10),(01),(11),(11)$

The new code has size 3 not 4 as the original one.
Here the link to the statement and the proof:
http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound

What is my mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code actually has distance 1, since $d(110, 111) = 1$.

Comment: Ok... So now I found another mistake that I am doing... Using Hamming-weight to fine the distance I should look at the number of components which are not equal to 0 for all vectors... What's going wrong?

Comment: The Hamming weight (usually denoted $w$) and Hamming distance (usually denoted $d$) are different things. The Hamming weight is the number of positions where the vector is nonzero: $w(\mathbf{x}) = |\{i \mid x_i \ne 0\}|$. The Hamming distance is the number of positions in which two vectors differ: $d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = |\{i \mid x_i \ne y_i\}|$. Note that $d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = w(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})$.

Comment: The (minimum) distance *of a code* $C$ is defined as $d(C) = \min_{\mathbf{x} \ne \mathbf{y} \in C} \, d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$.

Comment: (+1) @sky90: The minimum (non-zero) Hamming weight is equal to the minimum  Hamming distance, when the code is linear. Your example code is not.